# Models subpackages in Play framework

Tags: java, model, playframework-2.0

The list of classes in my `models` package is getting pretty big and I want to refactor some of the classes into their own subpackage.

For instance, all forms go into `models.forms`, all users go into `models.users`, etc.

However if I now declare a template that takes a form:

```
@(myForm : Form[MyForm])
```

This gives me a `not found: Type MyForm`-error.

I've tried importing the class:

```
@import models.form.MyForm
```

but this doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fully-qualify `MyForm` in the first line of your view template when declaring the input parameters:

```
@(myForm : Form[models.common.MyForm])
```

It is indeed a bit unintuitive that the `@import` entry doesn't make any difference. Perhaps the way in which view templates are compiled means that custom types have to be fully qualified if they occur before the list of imports.