# Packages added into /app/models are not recognized. Playframework2.1

Tags: java, refactoring, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Is it possible to modularize the app/models folder adding packages into it in play2.1 framework (java)?

Actually I have to put all of my classes (models) into app/models folder, otherwise play! framework can't find my classes on compilation time. I really don't like to have all of my classes into a single folder.

I did a research about play2 projects on github and most of them are simple and have all of their models into app/models with no packages into this folder as the samples bundled with the framework.

Do you add packages into app/models folder in your project? If so, do you have to configure something else?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many packages in the `models` package as you want, and I consider this good practice. I.e. this is how my current structure looks like:

```
/models
    /i18n        
    /forms
    /roles
    /utils
    /users
```

The only thing that you must change is that you must use the **fully qualified** name as parameter in templates. (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402582/models-subpackages-in-play-framework))
Besides that, if you call *static* methods, you must also use the full name: `@User.getUsername` becomes `@users.User.getUsername`.